# Visual Studio 2010 displays IIS 7 page on debug instead of my project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, configuration, windows-server-2008

This is my first ASP.NET project so I am a bit of a rookie when it comes to a lot of the configuring of IIS/Visual Studio so bear with me...

I am using Visual Studio 2010 running on Windows Server 2008 SR2.  We recently did some updates on the server and now my project no longer loads when I attempt to debug.  When I try to debug the default "Welcome" page for IIS 7 loads instead of my project.  I am set up to use the development server to debug, not IIS so I don't understand why I get the IIS page.  Before the updates the debugger was pulling up my page without any issues.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: probaly your iis have been reinstalled and your asp.net project is not configured in the default site. But cannot say with the limited information you provided.

Comment: Where would I go to configure the default site?

Comment: see this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972

Comment: no luck... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IIS is now bound to the port number that Visual Studio Development Web Server was using previously. You can change the port number in the properties of the web site project.

Comment: In Solution Explorer > Properties > Web > Servers I have it set to Use Visual Studio Development Server and it is set to Auto-Assign the port.  Is that what you were referring to?  Or were you talking about another setting?

Comment: Ok, if its set to auto assign port then it will grab any unassigned port, which may change over time. You should see an icon in your task bar for the VS web server, this will tell you what port your site is running on if you click on it

Comment: I think it is currently 61000.  Do I need to set it to a specific port?

Comment: What is the URL that your project is hitting after you debug? Also, When you say debug ... you mean visual studio debug (F5) or publish the website and debug from external source?

Comment: The URL is that of our website... this project but the current version available online.  It's as if it is trying to "go out to the internet" instead of showing the project running in the virtual server.  And by debug I mean Visual Studio debug (F5), not from an external source.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my issue.  I decided to use IIS instead of the Development Server for debugging.  After attempting to debug unsuccessfully yet again, I took a look at the identity that was being used in the application pool and I changed to one with more privileges and that seemed to do the trick.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but non-of the earlier answers worked.

I am using Windows 7 enterprise 64-bit, IE11, VS2010, Silverlight 5

I have been developing and maintaining a number of Silverlight projects for the past 5 years, and have always been able to debug them within VS2010 using the ASP.NET Development Server.  However, on returning from some well deserved holiday, I found that none of my existing Silverlight projects would run in the debugger.  In each case there is a Web project set as the start-up project, and in each case on starting the project within VS2010 (with or without debugging) I got the IIS7 web page instead of my application.

I tried creating a new Silverlight web application, and found that this started normally in the ASP.NET Development Server.  I checked my source code and found that no changes had been made in my absence.

After a lot of head scratching, etc., the solution was to clear the IE cache.  These are the explicit steps I used:

1. Close all instances of IE and ASP.NET Development Server.
2. Open Internet Properties from the Control Panel.
3. Click "Delete"  on the General Tab.
4. In the Delete Browsing History box check the following options:

   a) "Preserve Favourites website data"

   b) "Temporary Internet files and website data"

   c) "Cookies and website data"

   Leave the others unchecked

5) Click "Delete" and wait for the command to complete.

6) Close the Internet Properties box.

7) Rebuild ASP.NET project

8) Start (with or without debugging) in VS2010 - it should now load normally.

Hope this works for you.